# Call() is not public in android.telecom.Call, Cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, android, telephony, telephonymanager

I have the next class within SDK23 which should support playDtmfTone() :

```
import android.telecom.Call;

public class myDtmf {

    public void myPlayDtmfTone() {

        Call mytone = new Call();  // error here for Call()

        mytone.playDtmfTone('0');
    }
}
```

The Call() in the line 'Call mytone = new Call()' shows the error:

Call() is not public in android.telecom.Call, Cannot be accessed from outside package.

How can I make Call() public or make it accessible ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Call](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html) "Represents an ongoing phone call that the in-call app should present to the user.". You're not meant to create an instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, referring to the [Javadoc of `Call`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html):

> [Call] Represents an ongoing phone call that the in-call app should present to the user.

So it doesn't really make sense to "create" an instance of it, since that requires you actually to create an actual phone call to some endpoint.

---

In general, if a method is not accessible outside the package, you aren't supposed to access it - it is not part of the API that the class developer has provided. There are ways to access it - specifically, reflection - but this is hacky and it is massively unlikely to be the way that you are meant to use the class.

The class may provide you with some other means to create an instance, like a static factory method (or an external factory) - but, for the reasons outlined above, that doesn't make sense in this case either.

Comment: Andy,  Many thanks for this clear and helpful answer.  - Dirk

Comment: No worries. Please consider accepting the answer (click the tick on the left-hand side).